# Check if variable exists on class, if so, modify the value of this variable

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

Hello people of StackExchange, this is my first post, as I've tried my best to solve this on my own, and I cannot find a really good solution that matches the solution I have in AS3.

AS3 Code:

```
//create player
R.instance({_origin: this, _updatable: 1, _saveToXML: 1, _bodyType: "DYNAMIC", _type: "o_nape_player", _sprite: "idle/CharacterIdle", _x: -32, _y: -512});

//R.instance function exposed + showing how the parameters_ get's passed through
class RInstance {
    public static function create(parameters_:Object = null):Dynamic {
        var instance:XxxxObject = null;
        var _type:String = parameters_._type;

        switch (_type) {
            case "o_nape_player": instance =  new O_nape_player(parameters_);
        }
        parameters_._origin.addToArrayObject( instance );

        return instance;
    }
}

//o_nape_player.as
public function XxxxObject(parameters_:Object = null) {
    parameters = parameters_;
}

protected function set parameters(parameters_:Object):void {
    var parameter:String;
    for (parameter in parameters_) {
        this[parameter] = parameters_[parameter];
    }
    parameters_ = null;
}
```

So as the title says, in Haxe, how would I, set the class's variables, based on a bag of variables that are thrown at the class ready to be unpacked?

The closest I've gotten, but this is not the result I want, as it requires setter functions:

```
override public function set_parameters(object:Dynamic):Void {
    for (param in Reflect.fields(object)) {
        try {
            Reflect.callMethod(this, Reflect.field(this, "set" + param.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + param.substr(1)), [Reflect.field(object, param)]);
        } catch (e:Dynamic) {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time. Please, I must stress, as I just said, that is not the result I want, I want my Haxe code to line up as best as possible with my AS3 code, my AS3 code does not require setter functions, to set variables that belong to a class.

**TL;DR**

With all the code posted above, I can simply rephrase the question like so;
How can I replicate this as simple as possible in Haxe:
this[parameter] = parameters_[parameter];

Comment: If you target only AS3, with untyped, you can use array access on Object. http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#091A6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be in fact to use the `Reflect` APIs:

```
function setAs(other:Test)
{
    for (f in Reflect.fields(other))
        Reflect.setField(this, f, Reflect.field(other, f));
}
```

A more complete example: [Try Haxe #0a6C3](http://try.haxe.org/#0a6C3).

Notes:

- I've intentionally used APIs that ignore getters and setters and only copy raw data.  This might not be optimal for your use case, if necessary check `Reflect.getProperty` and `Reflect.setProperty`.
- Haxe can access object fields with a map-like syntax (`foo[field] =   bar[field] = val`) if you wrap them with the `haxe.DynamicAccess` abstract.  It's a wrapper on top of the `Reflect` APIs that's a bit more convenient, specially for when you're dealing with objects with unknown structures (where you would usually need to call `Reflect.hasField` many times).
- just as in your example, I've not added any runtime type checks; `Std.is`, `Std.instance` and `Type.typeof` will be useful if typing the `setAs` precisely isn't feasible.

Comment: Is it possible to read all the attributes on the current class in question, and the classes it extends?

In AS3, all attributes are read, including parent attributes.
In Haxe, using this method above, it is picking up attributes of the parent class only, not the current class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the parent class only, not the current class".  It should work, as you can see in (this new) [Try Haxe #13Ae0](https://try.haxe.org/#13Ae0).  Maybe you don't explicitly use – without the use of Reflection – that field anywhere else, and it gets removed by [Dead Code Elimination (DCE)](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-dce.html)?  Check out the output of building with `-D dce-debug` and/or try to use the `@:keep` metadata, as I've used in this example.